# Querying for a value existing in a model's list property in AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, bigtable

A sample model:

```
  class Foo(db.Model):
     id = db.IntegerProperty()
     bar = db.ListProperty(int, required=True)
```

1. How can I query using either Query or GqlQuery to return all **Foo** entities that have a given value in their **bar** property?
2. If I have a list of ids, is there a single filter that will return all entities whose **id** property is in that list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1.

If you use an equals query on a list property, it will check all items in the list:

```
search = 2
results = Foo.all().filter('bar =', search).fetch()
```

2.

You can use an IN filter, but note that internally this makes a datastore query for each item in the list, so it may be slow, and there are also a maximum of 30 internal queries per request.

```
items = [1, 2, 3]
results = Foo.all().filter("id IN", items).fetch()
```

See [Introducing Queries](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queriesandindexes.html#Introducing_Queries) for details for both 1 and 2, and [ListProperty](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ListProperty) for further details on 1.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you like me who could not get the above answer to work.

Using gae version 1.5.3

```
results = Foo.all().filter('bar =', search).fetch()
```

gives no results. But

```
results = Foo.all().filter('bar =', search).fetch(100)
results = Foo.all().filter('bar =', search)
```

gives results.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you can also use Gql.. this may have been a development that happened in the time since the question was asked

For question 1

```
wheres = 2
pageSize = 10
qry = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE bar = :1", wheres)
Foos = qry.fetch(pageSize)
```

For question 2

```
wheres = [ 1, 3, 44, 101 ]
pagesize = 10
qry = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE bar IN (:1)", wheres)
Foos = qry.Fetch(pageSize)
```

Watch out for the in query, though. It will actually execute N subqueries (one for each element in your IN clause). Here's the Gql documentation: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference